# MySQL and MariaDB replication

Tags: mysql, database-replication, mariadb

Did anyone configure the replication from mysql to mariadb if yes can let me know  how he did it thx in advance.

My problem occurred after getting replication to start and  the error is saying

`Error 'Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted' on query. Default database:`

I tries via Xtrabackup tool and also just by using mysqldump on other slave.
All methods werent work.

Regards 
Augustyn

Answer (score 0):

It works just fine for me, but I initialized the slave differently: stop master, rsync datafiles over, start slave and set replication parameters, start master.

Comment: ok i will try this way too let u know what was the result thx

Comment: ya is working thx for help

Comment: i just need run mysql_upgrade and all fine